# How to enter something into a program without arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing trouble with a code that I am working on.

#1 code

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
CardNme = input("Enter name: ")
print("Changing " + CardNme + " to monitor mode")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("ifconfig " + CardNme + " down && airmon-ng check kill && iwconfig " + CardNme + " mode monitor && ifconfig " + CardNme + " up")
exit(0)
```

#2 code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import time

print("Enabling Moniter mode")
time.sleep(0.5)
os.system("./start.py")
os.system("wlan0")
```

Now like the situation is that I want to use #1 code in #2 code, but as the #1 code doesn't have arguments, i cant do  `./start.py -i wlan0` or anything like that. Is there any other way round? Or just arguments.

Note: **I lack the knowledge to use arguments in python**

Comment: the simplest way is to use [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20argv#sys.argv), which is a list of everything what was on the command line. More advanced is to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which lets you define expected parameters, and then there are external libraries when you want to go all-in like [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first script to get the interface name from `sys.argv`. If that's not supplied, it can prompt.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    CardNme = sys.argv[1]
else:
    CardNme = input("Enter name: ")
print("Changing " + CardNme + " to monitor mode")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("ifconfig " + CardNme + " down && airmon-ng check kill && iwconfig " + CardNme + " mode monitor && ifconfig " + CardNme + " up")
```

Then change the second script to supply `wlan0` as an argument

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import time

print("Enabling Moniter mode")
time.sleep(0.5)
os.system("./start.py wlan0")
```